# Use a variabel as a class name in php or Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, php-7, cakephp3

I am trying to run a array of command from another command. somthing similar to cronjob but with a view edit add option by end user.
this is working :

```
                $fooCommand = new \App\Command\fooCommand();
                $barCommand = new \App\Command\barCommand();
```

but what i need is :

```
            $classes = [
                "foo",
                "bar"
            ];
            foreach ($classes as $class) {
                $otherCommand = new '\\App\\Command\\' .$class. Command();
                # code...
            }
```

something similar to that. iterate in an array and initiate the class. practically running the commands from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your classname and use [variables variable](https://www.php.net/language.variables.variable)

```
foreach ($classes as $class) {
    $_class = "\\App\\Command\\{$class}Command";
    $class_name = $class . 'Command';
    $$class_name = new $_class;
    # code...
}
```

Comment: i did it like this but yours is working to:$class = '\\App\\Command\\' . $action . 'Command'; $command = new $class();

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
foreach ($classes as $class) {
    $classWithNamespace = "\\App\\Command\\{$class}Command";
    $otherCommand = new $classWithNamespace();
}
```

[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ea7d2b38a2e0252b35bb8872477b6673be7315c)

Comment: i did it like this :$class = '\\App\\Command\\' . $action . 'Command';
                    $command = new $class();